# typings folder in visual studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, typescript, visual-studio-2015

When using [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) in an asp.net application using visual studio 2015, do we have to include the typings folder as part of the project?

I want to treat typings folder just like the bower_components folder. Don't want to check that folder and don't want to include this as part of my solution. Unfortunately, VS is not finding the typings if the folder is not included in my project. Is it possible to treat typings folder like bower_components folder? I am using VS 2015, VSTS (team services) as source safe.

[image: Project Structure]

Thank you,
Soma.

Comment: it is not necessary to include typings folder similar to bower_component and node_modules, can you add your project structure to check if something else is missing?

Comment: I have attached the project structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add a main.d.ts file (file name does not matter) inside your client folder hoping it has your `ts` source files, with below content and try,

```
 /// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />
```

Comment: Please see my updated project structure image. I have an index.d.ts file in typings folder, do I have to create a new one?

Comment: yes, it should be inside Client folder referencing to index.d.ts